# % operator for BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger

How to use `a % b` with big integers?

Example

```
...
BigInteger val = new BigInteger("1254789363254125");
...

boolean odd(val) {
   if (val % 2 != 0)
      return true;
   return false;
...
```

Eclipse says that operator `%` is undefined for `BigInteger`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the `mod` function in the BigInteger javadoc.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Like this:

```
BigInteger val = new BigInteger("1254789363254125");
public boolean odd(BigInteger val) {
    if(!val.mod(new BigInteger("2")).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Or as user Duncan suggested in a comment, we can take out the if statement altogether like so:

```
BigInteger val = new BigInteger("1254789363254125");
public boolean odd(BigInteger val) {
    return !val.mod(new BigInteger("2")).equals(BigInteger.ZERO));
}
```

Comment: If val %2 == 0 its an even number, not odd.

Comment: No need for an if statement, just `return !val.mod(new BigInteger("2")).equals(BigInteger.ZERO);`.

Comment: @Duncan Yep you're right. My 2012 self wasn't quite experienced enough to recognize that. I'll edit my response with your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend BigInteger.valueOf(2), this gives you also a cached object.

Answer (score 12):

A much more efficient way is to check the last bit.
If it is `0` (aka function `testBit(0)` will return `false` and the function `odd(BigInteger)` will return `true`) the number is odd, otherwise it is even.

```
public boolean odd(BigInteger i) {
    return !i.testBit(0);
}

odd(BigInteger.valueOf(1)); // false
odd(BigInteger.valueOf(2)); // true
odd(BigInteger.valueOf(101)); // false
odd(BigInteger.valueOf(100)); // true
```

Also it's less lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the method [remainder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#remainder-java.math.BigInteger-) of the class BigInteger in this way:

```
BigInteger result = a.remainder(b);
```

The assignment is due to the fact that BigInteger is immutable, so a won't be changed by the method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `val.mod(2)`.

BigInteger is an object. You can't use arithmetic operators on objects, that works only with primitives.

`%` only works with `java.lang.Integer` because that is implicitly cast (actually, it is called *unboxed*) to int. But BigInteger can not be unboxed. Unboxing / boxing (meaning object-to-primitive / primitive-to-object conversion) only works with `long`, `int`, `float`, `double`, `short`, `char`, `boolean` and `byte`.

Answer (score 1):

As BigInteger is a class and not a primitive*1, you do not use operators with it. Check the methods for BigInteger: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#mod(java.math.BigInteger)

*1: In the case of Integer, Float, you can use operators because the JVM automatically converts the object to its primitive value (autoboxing)