# Fibonacci sequence - How to calculate the sum of the first 100 even-values Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: java, performance, fibonacci

Fibonacci sequence is defined as a sequence of integers starting with 1 and 1, where each subsequent value is  the sum of the preceding two I.e.

```
f(0) = 1
f(1) = 1
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) where n>=2
```

My goal is to calculate the sum of the first 100 even-values Fibonacci numbers.

So far I've found this code which works perfectly to calculate the sum of even numbers to 4million , however I'm unable to find edit the code so that it stops at the sum of the 100th value, rather than reaching 4million.

```
public class Improvement {
  public static int Fibonacci(int j) {
      
      /**
       * 
       * Recursive took a long time so continued with iterative 
       * 
       * Complexity is n squared.. try to improve to just n
       * 
       */
            int tmp;
            int a = 2;
            int b = 1;
            int total = 0;

            do {
              if(isEven(a)) total +=a;
              tmp = a + b;
              b = a;
              a = tmp;      
            } while (a < j);

            return total;

          }

          private static boolean isEven(int a) {
            return (a & 1) == 0;
          }

          public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Notice there is no more loop here
            System.out.println(Fibonacci(4_000_000));
          }
        }
```

Just to show the console from @mr1554 code answer, the first 100 even values are shown and then the sum of all is 4850741640 as can be seen below:

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

[image: mr1554 code answer]

Comment: use BigInteger insteaf of `int` . `int` is 4 bytes with maximum size of `2^31-1`

Comment: Please read: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) --- As of now, the question is too broad. Please [edit] the post and clarify what concept exactly you are struggling with.

Comment: @Turing85 I've edit to clarify what my issue is, hope its clearer

Comment: thanks @sidgate I didn't know BigInteger was a thing but I'll look into it. MY aim is to calculate the sum of the first 100 even numbers so I think int with a max value of 2^31-1 would be sufficient?

Comment: "*`System.out.println(Fibonacci(4_000_000));`*" - And that's why copy-pasting code we do not fully understand is a bad idea...

Comment: "Complexity is n squared" is it? What makes it so?

Comment: *My aim is to calculate the sum of the first 100 even numbers* That is not what you said in your question. Nor is that a fibonacci series.

Comment: @AndyTurner because the code in my original post is iterative rather than recursive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said.

> My goal is to calculate the sum of the first 100 even-values Fibonacci numbers.

That number gets very large very quickly. You need to:

- use BigInteger
- use the mod function to determine if even

For this I could have started from `(1,1)` but it's only one term so ...

```
BigInteger m = BigInteger.ZERO;
BigInteger n = BigInteger.ONE;

BigInteger sumOfEven= BigInteger.ZERO;
int count = 0;
BigInteger t;
while( count < 100) {
    t = n.add(m);
    // check if even
    if (t.mod(BigInteger.TWO).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        sumOfEven = sumOfEven.add(t);
        count++;
    }
    n = m;
    m = t;
}
System.out.println(sumOfEven);
```

Prints

```
290905784918002003245752779317049533129517076702883498623284700
```

If, on the other hand, from your comment.

> My aim is to calculate the sum of the first 100 even numbers

Then you can do that like so

```
sumFirstNeven = (((2N + 2)N)/2 = (N+1)N

so (101)100 = 10100 and the complexity is O(1)
```

Comment: Hi @WSJ check my edited original post below for the result I was looking for using the code provided in the first answer . The console shows the first 100 even values and then the summation below. Looks like the BigInteger is not needed in the code? Or is yours similar? I know there’s more than one way to skin a cat

Comment: @WSJ After I specified the number of even elements of the Fibonacci sequence to sum which was ‘100’; the Fibonacci sequence that prints below and the sun is added automatically. I’m not sure what you mean by 11 values between 2 and 4,000,000. The sequence shown in the screenshot of the IDE/console  is 0, 2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16, 26, 42, 68, 110, 178, 288 etc.. so clearly there is more than 11? I’m not sure what you are referring to

Comment: Here is what I mean. You even said in your question that the series starts with 1,1. The accepted answer starts with 0 and 2. That is not the standard fibonacci series. If that is what you really wanted then may I suggest you edit your question and provide the first 5 terms of your desired sequence for clarification. I presumed you meant `1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,` etc. And sum only the even numbers. If that is wrong, I will delete my asnswer.

Comment: Ah I see I think you are right then! @WSJ I have overlooked that. The series should start with 1, 1 so I think you’re sequence 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34 etc is correct! So the sum should be 2 + 8 + 34 + etc until the first 100 even numbers have been added. I see now how the BigInteger is added but also why the first answer mentioned how it’s a sample code. Thanks for challenging me! I’ll look at you’re code again!

Comment: If you print each value in my answer you will see they start off with the familiar numbers and then increase in size dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `BigInteger` because `long` easily overflows as Fibonacci's scales quite easily. `BigInteger` is also tricky to check whether is an odd or even number, but you can use `BigInteger::testBit` returning `boolean` as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41151953/3764965).

Here is some complete code:

```
BigInteger fibonacciSum(int count, boolean isOdd) {
    int i = 0;
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger current = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger next = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger temp;

    while (i < count) {
        temp = current;
        current = current.add(next);
        next = temp;

        if ((current.testBit(0) && isOdd) || ((!current.testBit(0) && !isOdd))) {
            sum = sum.add(current);
            i++;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Or you can have some fun with Stream API:

```
BigInteger fibonacciSum(int count, boolean isOdd) {
    final BigInteger[] firstSecond = new BigInteger[] {BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE};
    return Stream.iterate(
            firstSecond, 
            num -> new BigInteger[] { num[1], num[0].add(num[1]) })
        .filter(pair -> 
            (pair[1].testBit(0) && isOdd) || 
            (!pair[1].testBit(0) && !isOdd))
        .limit(count)
        .map(pair -> pair[1])
        .reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger::add);
}
```

In any way, don't forget to test it out:

```
@Test
void test() {
    assertThat(
        fibonacciSum(100, false),
        is(new BigInteger("290905784918002003245752779317049533129517076702883498623284700")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as I figured,  you want a program to sum 100 first even values of the **Fibonacci** series.

here is a sample code, when you run the program it will ask you to determine the number of the even values, you want 100 value e.g, type 100 in consul:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int firstNumber = 0;
    int secondNumber = 2;
    System.out.print("Enter the number of odd elements of the Fibonacci Series to sum : ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int elementCount = scan.nextInt(); // number of even values you want
    System.out.print(firstNumber + ", ");
    System.out.print(secondNumber + ", ");


    long sum = 2;
    for (int i = 2; i < elementCount; i++) {
        int nextNumber = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        System.out.print(nextNumber + ", ");

        sum += (nextNumber);

        firstNumber = secondNumber;
        secondNumber = nextNumber;

    }
    System.out.print("...");

    System.out.println("\n" + "the sum of " + elementCount + " values of fibonacci series is: " + sum);
}
```

Comment: wow tf this is perfect.. how were you able to find it? Is there a site with sample codes to look at?

Comment: Also what would the time complexity of this be?

Comment: @RedRum unfortunately, I didn't find any sample that exactly be the answer of your question.